# If $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_{n + 1} - a_n) \to 0$ then $a_n$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Someone recently tried to claim that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_{n + 1} - a_n) = 0$ implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists. This is of course not true, as $a_n = \log n$ shows. In fact, even if $a_n$ is bounded the statement isn't true, as the sequence $$0,1,\frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, 1, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{2}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, 0, \ldots$$ shows.

What hypotheses can we make on a sequence $a_n$ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_{n + 1} - a_n) = 0$ implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists. The well known alternating series test tells us that the statement is true if $a_n$ is the sequence of partial sums of an alternating series. Are there less obscure hypotheses one can make?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test is a generalization of the alternating series test.

Comment: This is pretty much the same question as "what hypotheses on a sequence $(b_n)$ imply that $\sum_1^\infty b_n$ converges".

Comment: @MartinR how do you build a sequence satisfying the statement in the OP out of the Dirichlet test?

Comment: @AnginaSeng oh you're right. I didn't see that connection. So the OP is hopelessly general then? Still, are there any easy to state hypotheses that make the statement true?

Comment: I would like just to add that if we consider $p$-adic numbers (not $\mathbb{R}$), then this statement become true. If you want to learn more about that, see, for example, here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNumber.html

Comment: The bounded sequence you've given doesn't actually have $lim_{n \to \infty} (a_{n+1} - a_n) = 0$, because of the drops from 1 down to 0.   But $0, 1, 1/2, 0, 1/3, 2/3, 1, 3/4, 2/4, 1/4, 0, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1, 5/6, \ldots$ would serve as a counterexample.

Comment: @MichaelLugo shoot you're right. It worked in my head, but I guess I didn't think it through.

Comment: @MartinR: isn't Cauchy criterion a better idea in this case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test#Proof